# Why is the return statement executed before completion of the recursive function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, promise

The below `data` function is called by a get route. The problem I have is that I can't figure out why the `images` array remains empty on `return images` but shows as correctly populated at `console.log(images)` in my recursive `start(node)` function -- which performs a DFS by repeatedly calling the Microsoft Graph API and allocates `img` objects to the `images` array. I initialise the traversal after `res` contains the object tree.

I assumed that `return images` would execute only after the recursion is complete and `images` is populated, but that doesn't look to be the case. I think it's an asynchrony issue which I'm not too familiar with, so would appreciate any help or solution.

```
shelfdb.data = (accessToken) => {
    const token = accessToken;
    const endpoint = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/webgroup.sharepoint.com,23e7ef7a-a529-4dde-81ba-67afb4f44401,0fa8e0f7-1c76-4ad0-9b6e-a485f9bfd63c/drive/items/01GNYB5KPQ57RHLPZCJFE2QMVKT5U3NYY3/children'

    var res = callMsGraph(token, endpoint);

    var images = []

    function start(node) {
        if(node.value) {
            node.value.forEach(function(child) {
                var end = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/webgroup.sharepoint.com,23e7ef7a-a529-4dde-81ba-67afb4f44401,0fa8e0f7-1c76-4ad0-9b6e-a485f9bfd63c/drive/items/' + child.id + '/children';
                var result = callMsGraph(token, end);

                result.then(function(result) {
                    if (result.value.length > 0) {
                        if ('image' in result.value[0]) {
                            result.value.forEach(function(imgChild) {
                                let img = {
                                    'name': imgChild.name,
                                    'job': imgChild.parentReference.path.split("/")[6],
                                    'path': imgChild.webUrl
                                }
                                images.push(img);

                                console.log('images object:')
                                console.log(images);
                            })
                            
                            return;
                        }
                    }

                    start(result);
                })

            })
        }
    }

    res.then(function(result) {
        start(result);
    })

    return images;

};
```

Comment: asynchronous 101 - Your code does not sit around and wait for the then() to execute.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron

Comment: Everything you ever wanted to know, and more, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Could someone hold my hand with this? I'm having trouble applying start(node) as a callback and finding where to place `return images`.

Comment: making the parent `data` function `async` and `await start(res);` before `return images` still gives me an empty variable.